# "Look whose birthday is today?" is this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, grammaticality

I don't think it is.
It was written by one of those so-called English instructors on Instagram...
I personally think the correct form is Look whose birthday it is today...I could be wrong though.

Comment: Yes, it's grammatical. The more common and complete version is *look **at** whose birthday **it** is (today)*. But the omitted words are understood to be there.

Comment: so you are saying that "look whose birthday is today" is correct? how can it be?

Comment: There are a vast number of sentence constructions that are possible for expressing the same thing. It's also quite common to find sentences that are full of missing words, but whose meanings are still quite clear. A prime example is imperative sentences. Consider this sentence: *Go home!* The subject is missing. In full, it's really this: *[You (must)] go home!* But everybody knows that the subject is *you* in these sentences, and there is no need to explicitly write it out.

Comment: I got it thank you

Comment: 'Look whose car is in the car park' is certainly idiomatic and grammatical. 'Look whose birthday is today' is not exactly the same usage of be; although it may be grammatical, your suggested rewrite certainly sounds more idiomatic to my ears.

Answer (score -1):

The correct form appears to be "*Look whose birthday it is today?*". "At" is no used before wh- grammatical words (pronouns and determiners) but maybe not all.
This is justified by [OALD, look 3](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/look_1?q=look).

- Look what a beautiful chair they brought us!
- Look at whichever they've marked off and decide whether you like them.

Comment: "Look what beautiful chair they brought us" sounds strange. I think most people would say "Look at what a beautiful chair they brought us" or "Look at the beautiful chair they brought us".

Comment: @nnnnnn I agree with you on the count of something not quite adding up; however, this would be merely a missing indefinite article: "Look what **a** beautiful…". The form without "at" is, I think, quite well established, as you might verify from  [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22look%20what%20a%20beautiful%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1991,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en), and in fact there is no trace of "Look **at** what a beautiful". This confirms the OALD, which I use as a reference.